# $(R_{≤3}[X], +, \cdot)$ notation

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I am tutoring Linear Algebra, for an undergrad student of Mathematics and Economics at University of Aarhus. I have tutored Linear Algebra several times before at other universities and also at the same university, but in a different undergrad course. My new student wants me to go through old exam papers. I haven't met this notation before and cannot find it in the book they are following in their course ("Linear Algebra Done Right" by Sheldon Axler). In fact I haven't been able to find it in any of the Linear Algebra books I have.

[Screen shot of question from exam paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CMtR.png)

The question reads:

> $(R_{≤3}[X], +, ·)$, where + is the addition of polynomials and · is the multiplication of a polynomial by an element of the field R, is a
> real vector space of dimension 3.

This part of the paper is multiple choice and asks the student to answer true or false to the question.

Since I am unfamiliar with the notation I'm unsure how to answer the question.

Comment: It's hard to guess from what you have written...do you have a link?  If you want a raw guess, I would think it referred to the space of polynomials with real coefficients and degree $≤3$ with the usual operations.

Comment: $R_{\leq 3}[X]=\{a_0+a_1X+a_2X^2+a_3X^3\mid a_i\in R\}$ has dimension $4$.

Comment: Another wild guess is that $R_{\le 3} = (-\infty,3]$ and $R_{\le 3}[X]$ means polynomials in the variable $X$ such that all coefficients are contained in $(-\infty,3]$. But wild guesses is pretty much all we can do here, as opposed to definitive answers.

Comment: And without knowing what the notation means, it's impossible to say whether it describes anything.

Comment: Looks like the notation is $R_{\leq 3}[X] = \{f\in \mathbb{R}[X]:\, \deg f \leq 3\}$, and $(V, +, \cdot)$ denotes the (alleged) real vector space with underlying set $V$, addition operation $+: V \times V \to V$, and scalar action $\cdot : \mathbb{R} \times V\to V$.

Comment: That was also my thought, but I wasn't sure.

The last bit $+:V\times V\rightarrow V$ don't you mean: $+:V+ V\rightarrow V$?

Comment: A problem with old exam papers is that they may use notation known to the students who were examined, but unknown to us.

Comment: I agree, but the exam paper is from January, so I assume that it is the same curriculum (I could be wrong of course). But is is still that best guideance the students have to know what to expect for the exam (my own Alma Mater provides them w. answers as well as guidance on curriculum changes).

Comment: Thank you everyone. I think I have my question answered - I don't know how to respond to individual answers.